# What can cause a totally "disabled" UI?

Tags: android, android-layout

Since upgrading to Nougat, there are some situations when my app's UI is completely unresponsive to touches on my Nexus 5x even though all views are drawn and contain the correct contents; only the Back or Home key are effective to dismiss it. There have been a few rare occasions where it *does* work on my 5x, and there is also no problem with it working on an emulated 5x, which of course has no other 3rd-party apps installed, etc.

Since this app has worked flawlessly in this respect since its original release on Android 2.3, obviously something has changed. What I suspect is some sort of *race condition* during initialization, but I don't know where to start to figure out what is happening.

What is it that could be disabled so as to make the app's UI visible but unresponsive? Is there a place that I could insert a break or logging statement, or just look at settings to figure out what's happening?

Comment: "What is it that could be disabled so as to make the app's UI visible but unresponsive?" -- use Android Studio's layout inspector or `uiautomatorviewer`. One possibility would be if there is some transparent `View` that is higher on the Z axis than your main UI.

Comment: This question no longer active -- a basic mistake (from a long time ago) was found and corrected in the code.